# How to add Java options while installing a new tomcat service

Tags: tomcat, service, tomcat7

I am trying to set up java options example -DprojectValue=Code

But I am unable to set it up.

Please suggest some approaches to add/update for tomcat service.

Comment: Reference `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html` and navigate to the section `Command line arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update services from tomcat directory only. The service wouldn't be updated if use it from custom defined location for services.